# Can i use reduce to create a list of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to reduce a list of objects into another list of objects. Is this possible with this logic (not exact of course)?

```
p = someList.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  let {id, title} = item;
  accumulator.push({
    id: id,
    title: title
  })
},[])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Your implementation is correct, but is only missing `return accumulator;` at the end of the reducer function.

However, if each input item is being transformed into exactly one output item, I'd recommend `map` instead:

```
p = someList.map(({id, title}) => ({id: {id}, title: {title}}));
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP really meant `{id: {id}, title: {title}}` probably rather `{id: id, title: title}`.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but in that case I think the whole thing should be replaced by `p = someList` :)

Comment: true, unless the creation of brand new objects is crucial.

Comment: Thank you, forgot about the return.